# Pushing element into an array wont update on the UI

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to update an array after fetching the json data from the endpoint but i am not getting expected results on the front end.

```
export class LocationSectionComponent implements OnInit{


  myControl = new FormControl();
  options : string[] =  ['0089/PITT', '0085/CALI', '0090/MASS'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );

      this.fetchData();
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
        const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
        return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(value));
      }

   private fetchData ()
   {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:9090/api/v1/facility/1')
   .subscribe(responseData => {
    const facilityOrigin = responseData.facilityNumber +"/"+ responseData.name;
    this.options.push(facilityOrigin);
    console.log(this.options);
    });
   }
```

when I perform the push operation through fetchData() method gives me updated array like this

```
(4) ["0089/PITT", "0085/CALI", "0090/MASS", "89/PITT"]
0: "0089/PITT"
1: "0085/CALI"
2: "0090/MASS"
3: "89/PITT"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

but on the front end I can see only 3 options i.e `['0089/PITT', '0085/CALI', '0090/MASS']`. How can fix this issue. Is this a scope issue or something else?

Comment: using onpush strategy?

Comment: It's time to show us your template

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
this.options = [...this.options];  // after push
```

If you have set ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush for your component, you can try to call this.cdr.detectChanges();

see: [onpush-change-detection-how-it-works](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/)

Comment: I think you're on the right track with this response, but at that point why not forgo the `.push` altogether and simply rewrite it as `this.options = [...this.options, facilityOrigin]`?

Comment: In this case: sure!  It's just to explain that he need a new reference.

Comment: Put this in your template:    <pre>{{options|json}}</pre>

Comment: Perhaps you are using filteredOptions in your template?

Comment: What's in your template? filteredOptions  or options?  Have you this added?  <pre>{{options|json}}</pre>     What  do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.options = this.options.concat(facilityOrigin);
```

instead of

```
this.options.push(facilityOrigin);
```